# Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

I am developing an application with Flutter. I want to switch between pages but it throws an error **"Another exception was thrown: Explorer action requested with a context that does not contain an explorer"**. how can i solve.

My Code:

```
`ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TheyApp(),
                          ));
                    },
                    child: Text("GO LA"))`
```